How to change from 3.023.842.96 to the format of 3,023,842.96, and be able to sum the numbers?
How to change from 3.023.842.96 to the format of 3,023,842.96? I would like to be able to sum the numbers too.

Could try : =--TEXTJOIN({",",",","."},,TEXTSPLIT(A4,"."))

In your system, what are your decimal and thousands separators?

You should change the locale to the correct language that use the expected decimal and thousand separators. Don't replace the string, it won't work everywhere

You can use SUBSITUTE to take out all .'s from the string and then put but one . two characters from the left side.
If the list of your numbers start in A1 but this  following formula in B1 and pull down for the full column:
=--(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", ""), LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", ""))-2) & "." & RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", ""), 2))
Then to see the comma separators you can set the number format and enable Use 1000 Separator:

